# What does it mean when the ELM327 OBD2-reader gives two lines of info for 0100 request?

Tags: obd-ii, elm-327

I have an ELM327-based OBD2 reader that I can issue commands to when connected to a car. I'm running this on a 2015 Acura RDX.

When I issue the request `0100` to get supported mode 1 PIDs, I get the following two responses back:

```
41 00 98 3A 80 03
41 00 BF BF A8 93
```

My understanding is that if there are multiple ECUs that can respond to a request they will both answer, so this may be why there are two responses. Does this mean that if I now issue a request that both support, I should get two answers back? And if I issue a request that only one or the other supports, I should only get back one?

Comment: Maybe the reader is returning multiple lines of supported PIDs? If you decode the response does it make sense? OBD2 is limited to the engine computer and I would think that when they set up modules they would stay away from multiple responses to the same PID.

Comment: No, it is from multiple ECUs. This is well known behaviour. What is not clear is what happens when requests are issued that multiple ECUs know how to respond to.

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
AT H1
```

this will turn on headers, then do

```
0100
```

you will get something like

```
7E8 06 41 00 BE 3E A8 13
7E9 06 41 00 98 18 80 13
```

which says you are getting results from ECUs 7E8 (engine) and 7E9 (transmission)
if you are running on an 11bit CAN.  If you get

```
18 DA F1 18 06 41 00 88 18 00 13
18 DA F1 10 06 41 00 BE 5F A8 13
```

then its results from ECUs 18DAF110 (engine) and 18DAF118 (transmission) from 29 bit CAN.
If you just want to hear from the engine only then issue

```
AT CRA 7E8
```

for 11 bit CAN or

```
AT CRA 18DAF110
```

for 29 bit CAN
dont forget to issue

```
AT H0
```

to turn headers back off

Comment: I would like to know what ECU's are on the bus. What is the most elegant way to find that out. I could set `AT CRA 18DAF10 to 1F' and see if somebody is answering and than filter based on the answers. But what would be the command to ping the Unit? (for 29 bit CAN)

Comment: Any ideas what to do in case it is not CAN?